# How to create different layout for Nexus 4 and similar devices? (Galaxy S4)

Tags: android

The question is how create a specific layout for Nexus 4 and similar devices?

4.7" diagonal
1280 x 768 pixel resolution (320 ppi)
WXGA IPS

Comment: read here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Yes. The idea is not build a specific for Nexus 4, but for similar devices resolutions and inchs. What is the right layout folder layout-sw***dp?. I am going to change the title.

Comment: @kcoppock I think it's not as unreasonable as it seems. For instance, the Nexus 7 tends to get a "phonish" layout instead of a "tabletty" layout if you rely on the default device config buckets. Putting a tabletty layout in that particular bucket ruins the experience on older 7" tablets with much lower resolution. The Nexus 4 is in a similar spot compared to older phones.

Comment: @Barend If you use `sw600dp`, the Nexus 7 will pull from that. If you're still using the old `large` and `xlarge` differentiators it may not. @ZeusMonolitics what *exact* problem are you trying to target?

Comment: @kcoppock I know, but from your comment there was no way for me to tell that you did too :-).

Answer (score 3):

For Nexus 4 should load the same layout that Galaxy S3

Galaxy S3
Screen Size: 4.8 inch
Screen Resolution: 1,280 x 720 pixels

And the configuration should be:

1. For same layout landscape and portrait layout-sw360dp
2. Only for landscape layout-sw360dp-land
3. Only for portrait layout-sw360dp-port

Other similar devices:

- LG Optimus 4X HD
- HTC One X+

For Galaxy S4 should also compatible and load this layout

The response was in this entry: [Android S3 layout vs Galaxy Nexus layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699761/android-s3-layout-vs-galaxy-nexus-layout/12557007#12557007)

Answer (score 2):

You can create layout directories for specific combinations. For 7" 1280 x 768 at 320 ppi it will look something like this:

```
layout-sw600p-xdpi-large
```

As @Tomer Mor mentioned, you can find a full list of available parameters [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Also, if you want to be even more specific about device parameters, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082868/android-does-not-honor-ldpi-qualifier) - you can assign different layouts from code, depending on the environment.